# python solving equations for unknown variable

Tags: python

is there any way where by i can solve an equation for its unknown value (without transposing) in python. are there any libraries which do this sort of calculations.
eg: W=mg
w=60,g=9.81 m=?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+equation+solver Fifth result.

Comment: @DanRedux good thing all numbers is a finite set or that might take awhile :) @OP why do you not want to transpose it? `m = W / g`

Comment: xyzsolve does a fine job.... also trying to find sympy capabilities. Basically i have been using spreadsheet for modelling math problems and using the goal seek feature for finding answer to unknown variable. it would be really helpful if you guys can suggest any other tool for the same purpose...

Answer (score 4):

Try SymPy

```
In [1]: from sympy import *

In [2]: m = Symbol('m')

In [3]: g = 9.81

In [4]: w = m*g

In [5]: solve(w - 60, m)
Out[5]: [6.11620795107034]
```

Answer (score 0):

The scipy optimize package provides robust implementations of the most commonly used algorithms for solving equations numerically. For more information on the different types as well as how to use them check out the tutorial page here:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.10.1/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in sympy:

Overview:

> SymPy is an open source Python library for symbolic mathematics. It
>   aims to become a full-featured computer algebra system (CAS) while
>   keeping the code as simple as possible in order to be comprehensible
>   and easily extensible. SymPy is written entirely in Python and does
>   not require any external libraries.

http://code.google.com/p/sympy/