# How to find variable of an equation where x-intercept is 0

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following equation and I'm trying to solve it similar to how Goal seek works in excel.  Currently I'm attempting to do this with sympy.

Equation:

```
(-0.0108242189900525*(x*x)) + (-0.127049195945013*x) + 0.00668862850925914*45.78) + 0.688105530515927
```

In excel I would use Goal seek and the set cell would be the above equation.  x would be F2 in excel for this example.
The to value: 0
By changing cell: F2

I need to write a python algorithm to solve for x where the x-intercept is 0.
If I run the above equation it will find an X-intercept of -0.000219998 by changing F2 to 5.3706.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this with sympy and solve similar to
[python solving equations for unknown variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274236/python-solving-equations-for-unknown-variable)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Here are the docs for sympy solve: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html?highlight=solve#sympy.solvers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example, except with shorter constants that approximate yours.

```
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x')

#I use approximate constants because I'm lazy
c1 = -0.0108
c2 = -0.1270
c3 = 0.006*46
d = 0.688

solve(x*x * c1 + x*c2 + c3 + d, x)
>>> [-17.0074912319716, 5.24823197271239]
```

And the second, 5.248..., is the approximate form of your answer 5.3706, and the error is caused by my not entering in all 20 digits of each constant.

Comment: Thanks.  I had to change solve(x*x * c1 + x*c2 + c3 + d, d) to solve(x*x * c1 + x*c2 + c3 + d, x).  After that it worked great.  What is the -17 value?

Comment: It's a quadratic equation, so you expect two answers.

Comment: Well that makes sense.  I was just given the data and didn't even think about it being quadratic.  I should have graphed it.  Thanks again.